# How can i control Wi-Fi device from its API using MQTT

Tags: wifi, mqtt

I have a Wi-Fi speaker device and want to control from its API's using MQTT.
Is there any possibility to send API to Wi-Fi device (Play, Pause and resume) using MQTT.
When tried to control (Play, Pause and resume) from API it gives "OK" as feedback. I have checked these using POSTMAN.

Note: I cannot change any code in WI-FI Speaker.

Comment: This is the API command to pause:   "http://192.168.17.1/httpapi.asp?command=setPlayerCmd:onepause"

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own bridge between MQTT and the HTTP API.